# Why, algorithm and data structure, both are not considered together when doing Big O complexity analysis?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o, time-complexity

I have been reading about algorithms and data structures & their performance characteristics. I want to understand - How running time of a program is affected by the Big O complexity analysis of a particular algorithm against a particular data structure. For e.g. in a Red-Black Tree structure, searching in worst case, can take o(log (n)) time (http://bigocheatsheet.com/). However, if algorithm/sorting method that is been chosen for a red black tree structure, is slow, for e.g. bubble sort or selection sort, then would not it will yield bad performance overall for the program ? Isn't it important to take both (algorithm and data structure) together into account when doing Big O complexity analysis ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing green apples with red apples here.

Take your example, for instance - a Red-Black Tree's insert and remove methods keep it balanced. So when you search for a value, worst case O(log(n)) is because there's no sorting of any kind done. The tree is already "sorted" according to a predefined policy (the tree's invariant, if you would) and its' height is at O(log(n)), so searching takes no more than O(log(n)) in performance. It's not an array, but a tree. It is been sorted as you build it.

If you want to look at the performance of the overall program, then you should mostly consider series of instructions and operations performed in batch (they usually determine how bad the performance is). In which case, yes, you should take into account all variables that might affect your performance. If you're sorting at any point, then, yes, take that into consideration. As I've said, Red-Black Tree does not sort on search.

When examining an overall batch performance, it is highly recommended to consider the *amortized* performance. Getting back to your Red-Black Tree example, you might expect n insertions into an empty tree (building the tree, that is) to take O(nlog(n)) since you're doing n O(log(n)) operations, however actually it takes O(n) operations since you reach the worst case in only a fraction of these operations. I suggest you read on that subject as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if a red-black tree is a good example. But in general:

The complexity of operations of a data structure depends on the algorithms used in it (if there are any used). But you don't want to say "If I use a bad algorithm, the complexity would be ...". You always use the sub algorithm with the best possible complexity.

Implementations may differ from the complexity of the theoretical algorithm/complexity. maybe you have a special use case, where you can use a better sub algorithm, or algorithms with a worse complexity but better constant factors (this sometimes matters).